# is there any ways to create flutter project with some default codes?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to find a way to create new flutter application with the pre-built script. For example if i have a set of .dart files already, is it possible to use these files to create a new flutter application?

Comment: what kind of dart files? I use code_builder for code generation, and run `flutter create` programmatically and replace the file content with code generated by code_builder programmatically..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [Github issue for this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/77104), but it is not yet resolved.